# Android TCP socket connection with server whose IP is dynamically assigned

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

Someone please help, I have two devices connected to a wifi router. One of the device is android mobile which works as a TCP client and the other device is a wifi module which works as the TCP server. I am able to open a TCP socket and send message but the problem is the IP address of the wifi module is getting changed by the WiFi router because of DHCP. How can i know the IP address of my WiFI module dynamically Please let me know if any of these methods work or which of these would be a better option or any other better option available that this

1. Send a broadcast TCP message(i know broadcast are not allowed in TCP and is one to one protocol but in any way that i can do)
2. Access wifi routers ARP cache table and get the ip address corresponding to that mac address
3. Do an RARP for a particular mac address    -Ping every device on the subnet until i find my device(which im not comfortable doing
       it)

I want the solution in android.Somebody please help.

Thanks

Comment: For #1, use UDP instead. You can send a message to the broadcast IP of the subnet that both devices are connected to. Otherwise, if the Wifi module has a DNS hostname assigned to it, try connecting to that instead of the IP directly, and let the router figure it out for you. Otherwise, just have the Wifi module display its current IP and enter that into the Android app when needed.

Comment: None of these will work for me. Any other solution.. Please someone help..

Comment: Why can't you do a UDP broadcast? That would be the simplest solution, unless the Module does not support UDP. Otherwise, you may have to resort to making the client perform a brute port scan of the sunbet, which you said you don't want to do. Any efficient solution is going to involve the Module broadcasting or publishing its current IP where the client can access it.